# Were transducers in the Reducers library in Clojure 1.5 all along?

Tags: clojure, reducers, transducer

I heard a comment made today:

> "Tranducers were there all along, they came with the [reducers in 1.5](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html)"

Indeed - Richs's [Anatomy of a Reducer blog entry](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/15/anatomy-of-reducer.html), bears remarkable resemblance to the [logic used in his Strange Loop Transducers talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII). (Replace 'transformers' with 'transducers').

My question is: **Were transducers in the Reducers library in Clojure 1.5 all along?**

Comment: It sure looks like the same idea, or at least the origins of the same idea. I don't think that the modifications to the API were there however (i.e. that `(map)` returns its native transducer etc). I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes. From Rich's [Transducers are Coming](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2014/8/6/transducers-are-coming): *Two years ago ... describing how reducers work, I described the reducing function transformers on which they were based ... these transformers were never exposed a la carte ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy is correct, the Idea what there though not accessible as it's own thing. Specifically `map` `filter` `reduce` etc. where not yet capable of producing a transducer and `into` `chan` `sequence` where not available to consume them, so in my opinioin it is safe to say that transducers where *not* present in Clojure < 1.6.0